# Disable black screen when lock button pressed

Tags: android

I want to disable the black screen appearing when i press the lock button in android. You might have observed how they do it in android video players just place a lock icon on the top instead of bringing up the black screen. Please tell to which classes or methods to refer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By black screen I asume that you mean that the screen turns off.

Use the [powermanager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) for that. By acquiring a [wakelock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html) you prevent the screen from turning off.

Comment: I tried your solution. Now the screen remains woken up. But I wanted that the lock button should not turn the screen black. any ideas?

Comment: my code: PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        
mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock( PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag"); 
mWakeLock.acquire();

Comment: @mayur: That is not possible. It would be very user unfriendly when programs prevent the device turning off.

Comment: I that is possible. It it were not then how does the Android Video Player do it? When you are watching a video and then you push the lock button the screen doesnt go black but a rather a lock icon appears on the top right. What do you think?